# How to loop through a DataGrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

I know this may sound like a very basic question but most examples I find are for GridView.

I just want to a foreach loop that goes through each row of the DataGrid. 
`DataGrid dgDetails = new DataGrid();`

I tried `foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in dgDetails.Items)`

but it skipped over this because it didn't find any Items.

I want to do something like this:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowIndex % 10 == 0 && row.RowIndex != 0)
    {
         row.Attributes["style"] = "page-break-after:always;";
    }
 }
```

But I need to change it to work for a DataGrid. I am trying to insert a page break after the tenth row.
But I know DataGrid does not contain a definition for 'Rows' so what can be used instead?

Comment: Tried using `foreach (DataGridRow dgRow  in dgDetails.Rows)` ?

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal that causes the error: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: May be foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridviews.Rows)

Comment: @MamunReza still get same error

Answer (score 2):

As previously noted in the comments of the question, DataGrid does not have a .Rows method.  Using `foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in dgDetails.Items)` is the way to iterate through the rows of a DataGrid.  You will need to make sure to set your source and do a data bind before doing the `foreach` loop.

```
    DataGrid dgDetails = new DataGrid();
    dgDetails.DataSource = your source
    dgDetails.DataBind();
    foreach (DataGridItem dataGridItem in dgDetails.Items)
    {
        //Do things with the dataGridItem here.
    }
```